# ~100% CPU Usage with little CPU Process utilization

Tags: windows-7, cpu, performance, cpu-usage

Fresh install Windows 7 on single core desktop.   Windows Task Manager:

- Performance Tab: spikes to ~100% CPU usage for long periods (30+ seconds)
- Processes Tab: sum of CPU column is < 4%

Windows Update -> Install Updates seems to cause trigger this event.  Is there a simple / clever technique to determine if there are any other services that are significantly consuming CPU usage?

Comment: If downvoting, please leave a constructive comment or better-yet modify the question.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue eventually?

Answer (score 1):

To check to see what **Windows service** is using significant amounts of CPU, visit [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/642474).

If you're not 100% sure whether or not a Windows service is using your CPU, open Task Manager as an administrator: search for Task Manager in your Start menu, right-click on Task Manager, click Run as administrator, click Yes if a prompt pops up, go to the Details tab, and sort by CPU. You can slow down the update speed under the View menu if the list changes too fast. If `svchost.exe` is using a lot of your CPU, a Windows service is the culprit, and you need to follow the above directions. Otherwise, the executable shown is the culprit.